# Verify whether pom.xml is correct maven 2.x

Tags: validation, maven, pom.xml

I generated the equivalent `pom.xml` from the `project.xml` which was built for a project based on maven 1.x, using the maven 2.1.0 version, with the following command

```
mvn one:convert
```

The `pom.xml` file was generated, and I edited it a lot, as I don't needed many of the things. Later, importing this project into eclipse Helios using **Import** --> **Existing Maven project**, I tried to import the project, but that gave me following warning and won't let me continue, as the **Finish** button was disabled.

[image: maven]

So, is there any way, I can validate the pom.xml as I am not able to figure out from the above, as there is no other meaning message. Probably, the xml might have messed up, or a unknown tag might have come due to wrong editing. Not sure.

Comment: The file might be there and valid, but that error might be a file permissions problem, or the file could be locked by your editor

Comment: @bohemian The auto-generated file is easily imported into eclipse. There above error is with the edited one. So, there is no permissions problem.

Comment: Just do an mvn clean on command line which will check the pom.xml and print out the information you need.

Comment: @khmarbaise that's correct. Was about to post it. There was a tag which is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pom.xml is a XML Document after all.

Its 'header' has some extra tags for Schema Validation, so any regular Validating Editor could work (actually, even browsers - including IE -, are able to validate your pom.xml for crude XML Errors)

Why don't you simply open the pom.xml from Eclipse as a regular XML file?

(Hint: Copy/Paste into an existing project, perhaps under a different name, then in Project Explorer, Right Click the pom. Select "Open With" | "XML Editor")

Chances are that it will grab 80% of the problems.

*(I'd dare to say the other 20% might be hidden under the "Error Log" View in Eclipse.)*

Comment: This also helped in some ways.

Comment: Can you bring some detail?

Comment: Eclipse showed a error mark, but the message was not meaningful. Just a error mark at the first line. Googling which, showed some discrepancy with the tags as a possibility. Have given the solution in my answer.

Answer (score 6):

I tried to do a `mvn clean`, from the command line, which showed that the tag `<id>` in the `<contributors>` is not defined.

I had added this tag on similar lines to `<developer>` tag, but `<id>` is not a part of `<contributors>`, which was the error that lead project not being imported into eclipse.

Removing this, project was easily imported.